# Vue-toastr and Vue2 how to set global options for toastr?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, toastr

I'm using [vue-toastr](https://github.com/s4l1h/vue-toastr) on my Laravel 5.5 and Vuejs 2 project.

The toasts are being showednormally, but I want to set some options globally for the toasts, like position...

I can't do this.

In my app.js file I've imported toastr from vue-toastr, required the styles and then `Vue.component('vue-toastr', Toastr);`.

I've tried `this.$refs.toastr.defaultPosition = "toast-bottom-left"` on my app.js like the docs say but it gives me an error `Cannot read property 'toastr' of undefined`

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

As covered [in the documentation](https://github.com/s4l1h/vue-toastr#with-npm--babel):

> Add component html: for vue 1.x
>
> ```
> <vue-toastr v-ref:toastr></vue-toastr>
> ```
>
> Add component html: for vue 2.x
>
> ```
> <vue-toastr ref="toastr"></vue-toastr>
> ```

Then you can use

```
this.$refs.toastr.defaultPosition = "toast-bottom-left"
```

Comment: as I've said in my question, I have done this, but into my app.js, wich is my main Vue file...
but then I get an error. I don't want to use this confiuration every time I call toastr

Comment: @JDalri No, you do not say in your question that you added the component to your template anywhere. You only say you registered it.